# Getting what I think is a part of the query string using python 2.7/CGI

Tags: python-2.7, url, cgi, query-string

I know I am using the wrong search terms and that's why I haven't been able to suss out the answer myself. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to use the CGI module to pull what I think counts as a query string from the url.

given a url `www.mysite.com/~usr/html/cgi.py/desired/path/info` how would one get the `desired/path/info` out of the url? I understand GET and POST requests and know I can use CGI's `FieldStorage` class to get at that data to fill my Jinja2 templates out and such. But now I want to start routing from a landing page with different templates to select before proceeding deeper into the site. I'm hoping the context is enough to see what I'm asking because I am lost in a sea of terms that I don't know.

Even if it's just the right search term, I need something to help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help on what was actually not to complicated a question. What I was looking for was a router/dispatcher that is usually handled by a framework fairly simply though an `@route` or something similar. Opting for a more efficient approach all I had to do was `import os` and then look at `os.environ.get('PATH_INFO', '')` for all the data I could possibly need. For anyone else following the path I was, that is how I found my way.